# How to group by on a newly created column with alias of the old column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to modify a column keeping the alias of the old column. But when I group by on it an error occurs.

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (
 number1 integer,
 number2 integer,
 name text
)
```

with new alias it works:

```
SELECT number1-number2 AS new_number FROM some_table GROUP BY new_number
```

But once I want to keep the old column name:

```
SELECT number1-number2 AS number1 FROM some_table group by number1
```

*column "some_table.number2" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function*

I can solve this problem two way:

1.wrapping it under another select

```
SELECT new_number AS  number1 FROM (
SELECT number1-number2 AS new_number  FROM some_table GROUP BY new_number) AS query
```

2.providing column number in the 'group by' clause

```
SELECT number1-number2 AS number1  FROM some_table GROUP BY 1
```

Is there a way to keep the old alias somehow without the provided solutions above?

Comment: You can't even group by new_number in MS SQL Server.

Comment: @SQL Hacks.     You have right , I forgot to mention that I tested it in postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query is the best way to write such query. You should always use alias names that are different from the column names.

Your second query is incomplete, which is somewhat obfuscated by using an alias name that equals a column name. Alias names defined in the `SELECT` clause cannot be used in the `GROUP BY` clause, as the latter happens before the former. So what you have is:

```
SELECT number1-number2 AS number1 FROM some_table
GROUP BY some_table.number1
```

while you need

```
SELECT number1-number2 AS number1 FROM some_table
GROUP BY some_table.number1, some_table.number2
```

or without the table qualifier:

```
SELECT number1-number2 AS number1 FROM some_table 
GROUP BY number1, number2
```

(Which still makes hardly any sense without any aggregation taking place of course, but I know, this is just an example :-)

Anyway, it is still a bad idea to re-use a column name for the alias. Imagine `ORDER BY number1` - what would that refer to; the column name or the alias name? (I am pretty sure the alias name has precedence here, but I don't know if this is actually defined to be so by the SQL standard.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cross apply`:

```
SELECT v.new_number
FROM some_table t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (t.number1 - t.number2)) v(new_number)
GROUP BY v.new_number;
```

You can also do:

```
SELECT v.number1
FROM some_table t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (t.number1 - t.number2)) v(number1)
GROUP BY v.number1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the result column number instead of the name.

eg:

```
GROUP BY 2
```